# multiply each number inside arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, multiplication

Write a program that allows a user to enter a number of values, the program should then convert the values entered in pounds (GBP) into a number of different currencies.  The menu should look something like this:

1. Enter values and type -1 to stop
2. Euros
3. Dollars
4. Yen
5. Rupees
6. Exit

When 2, 3, 4 or 5 are selected the program should display each value entered in both the original pounds and the converted currency, along with a total of all numbers and converted total.

```
public class Money {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter values and type -1 to stop"); 
        System.out.println("'1' = Euros"); 
        System.out.println("'2' = Dollars"); 
        System.out.println("'3' = Yen"); 
        System.out.println("'4' = Rupees"); 
        System.out.println("'5' = Exit"); 

        int count=0;
        String exit = "-1", euro="E";

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Convert to: ");

        while (!scan.hasNext("[E, D, Y, R, X]+")) {
            System.out.print("Invalid value, enter Surname again: ");
            scan.next();
        }

        String exTo = scan.next();

        ArrayList<String> num = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (true) {
            count++;
            System.out.print("|| Enter values "+count+" in (P)Pounds : ");

            while (!scan.hasNextDouble()) {
                System.out.print("Invalid value, try again: ");
                scan.next();
            }
            num.add(scan.next());

            if(num.contains(exit)){
                String ar[]=num.toArray(new String[num.size()]);
                ar=num.toArray(ar);

                System.out.println("Result: "+ num);

                scan.close();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How to multiply each number inside array list like

User type in numbers inside array list
array looks like this:[ 20, 30, 40 ]

and after I need that the result display like each number multiply for example by 2
[ 40, 60, 80 ]

Comment: )))) Or any other way to collect numbers from user, save them for example inside array and display all numbers multiplied by chosen value

Comment: users type in numbers (in pounds)
 ArrayList<String> num = new ArrayList<String>();
then user for example select convert to euros, and EACH value inside arraylist multiply by euros rate(for example by 0.94) and display to user arraylist but in euros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
import java.util.*;
class Money {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter values and type -1 to stop"); 
        System.out.println("'1' = Euros"); 
        System.out.println("'2' = Dollars"); 
        System.out.println("'3' = Yen"); 
        System.out.println("'4' = Rupees"); 
        System.out.println("'5' = Exit"); 
    int count=0;
    String exit = "-1", euro="E";

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Convert to: ");

    while (!scan.hasNext("[E, D, Y, R, X]+")) {
        System.out.print("Invalid value, enter Surname again: ");
        scan.next();
    }

    String exTo = scan.next();

    ArrayList<String> num = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (true) {
        count++;
        System.out.print("|| Enter values "+count+" in (P)Pounds : ");

        while (!scan.hasNextDouble()) {
            System.out.print("Invalid value, try again: ");
            scan.next();
        }
        num.add(scan.next());

        if(num.contains(exit)){
            for(int i=0;i<num.size();i++){
            num.set(i,Integer.toString((Integer.parseInt(num.get(i))*2)));
            }
            System.out.println("Result: "+ num);

            scan.close();
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

to remove the last input (-1)

add this line before print `num.remove("-1");`

Comment: users type in numbers (in pounds)
 ArrayList<String> num = new ArrayList<String>();
then user for example select convert to euros, and EACH value inside arraylist multiply by euros rate(for example by 0.94) and display to user arraylist but in euros

Comment: Is any way to do what I asked with strings? as well can't use integers, because have to collect numbers like 0.676567 and etc...

Comment: Sample input?? the code  at the actual question at the to, I collect all numbers into array the only bit where I'm struggle is to multiply arraylist by 2 , always errors when I do it...

Comment: input should be like 50.546453645 or 5045 without letters or any other symbols.

this what I try to do


`if(num.contains(exit)){
String ar[]=num.toArray(new String[num.size()]);
ar=num.toArray(ar);

for (int i=0; i<ar.length; i++) {


if(exTo.contains(euro)){
ar[i]*=2;
System.out.println("Result: "+ ar[i]);  
}
}
scan.close();
break;
}`

Comment: Thaaaanks)))) sorry can't vote up ...not enough reputation) It works)

Answer (score 0):

> How to multiply each number inside array list like User type in
>   numbers inside array list array looks like this:[ 20, 30, 40 ] and
>   after I need that the result display like each number multiply for
>   example by 2 [ 40, 60, 80 ]

how about loop through the list, and do the calculation?

```
for (Integer i : yourList)
  i *= 2;
```

or you could try with guava, `Lists.transform(list, func)`if you want to do more complex calculation.

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform(java.util.List, com.google.common.base.Function)

Comment: users type in numbers (in pounds)
 ArrayList<String> num = new ArrayList<String>();
then user for example select convert to euros, and EACH value inside arraylist multiply by euros rate(for example by 0.94) and display to user arraylist but in euros